# AutoHotKey script. Corrects duplicate characters if the interval between inputs is less than 150 milliseconds

Tags: autohotkey, keyboard-events

Please help.
I have a keyboard (Rapoo E9260) with a defect: characters are randomly doubled when I type.
I need a way to fix this defect. Perhaps an .ahk script.

For example, if a character "a" is entered and the same character is entered after less than 150 milliseconds, then the extra character will be deleted, or the "aa" will be replaced with "a". Else, if the interval between inputs is more than 150 milliseconds – no action.

Sample (not working):

```
#NoEnv
SendMode Input

previousKey := ""
previousTime := 0

SetTimer, DeleteDuplicate, -150

DeleteDuplicate:
    currentTime := A_TickCount
    if (currentTime - previousTime < 150)
    {
        SendInput {Backspace}
        SendInput {%previousKey%}
    }
    previousKey := ""
    previousTime := 0
return

$*::
    currentKey := A_ThisHotkey
    currentTime := A_TickCount
    if (currentKey = previousKey && currentTime - previousTime < 150)
    {
        previousKey := currentKey
        previousTime := currentTime
        return
    }
    previousKey := currentKey
    previousTime := currentTime
return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force

#UseHook

keys = a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0 ;...
Loop,Parse,keys, `,
    Hotkey, %A_LoopField%, DeleteDuplicate
return

DeleteDuplicate:   
    If (A_PriorHotKey = A_ThisHotkey AND A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 300)
        return ; don't send it
    SendInput, %A_ThisHotkey%
return
```

**EDIT:**

If you are using multiple keyboard layouts for different languages, replace each key in "keys" by its **[scancode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys)** and `SendInput, %A_ThisHotkey%`by `SendInput, {%A_ThisHotkey%}`.

E.g. on my system SC01E is the scancode for the a key, SC030 for b, SC02E for c, SC020 for d, and this works in all keyboard layouts:

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force

#UseHook

keys = SC01E,SC030,SC02E,SC020
Loop,Parse,keys, `,
    Hotkey, %A_LoopField%, DeleteDuplicate
return

DeleteDuplicate:   
    If (A_PriorHotKey = A_ThisHotkey AND A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 300)
        return ; don't send it
    SendInput, {%A_ThisHotkey%}
return
```

And make sure that your script is saved as [UTF-8 with BOM](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/FAQ.htm#nonascii).

Comment: I have multiple keyboard layouts and conflicts occur when I enter characters.

When I want to enter a character from another layout other than the Latin alphabet, I enter the character that is written in "keys", and which corresponds to the character from another layout.

Is it possible to make sure that any character entered from the keyboard is processed, and not just those that are pre-recorded in the keys set?

I tried to enter characters from a different layout into "keys", but then on the contrary, only characters of this layout are entered, but not Latin ones..

Comment: Use this [scriptlet to find the scancode](https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/21105-crazy-scripting-scriptlet-to-find-scancode-of-a-key/#entry138256) of each key

Answer (score 0):

```
#If !GetKeyState("CapsLock", "T")
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force

#UseHook

keys = SC029,SC010,SC011,SC012,SC013,SC014,SC015,SC016,SC017,SC018,SC019,SC01A,SC01B,SC01E,SC01F,SC020,SC021,SC022,SC023,SC024,SC025,SC026,SC027,SC028,SC02B,SC02C,SC02D,SC02E,SC02F,SC030,SC031,SC032,SC033,SC034,SC035 

Loop,Parse,keys, `,
    Hotkey, %A_LoopField%, DeleteDuplicate
return

DeleteDuplicate:   
    If (A_PriorHotKey = A_ThisHotkey AND A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 110)
        return ; don't send it
    SendInput, {%A_ThisHotkey%}
return
```

Comment: I would be better if you add some explanation how your code works.